# Binding a tmux key to multiple commands

Tags: tmux

I launch multipane tmux window to monitor several server parameters.
With Ctrl-S I can open a new window with another monitor command.

Now I want to bind Ctrl-Q to open another *multipane* window with several monitors. How do I bind a key to multiple commands?
I tried chaining them with ; and \; - nothing helps. Please, advise what should I use instead of **...** below.

Is it possible when I open a new window to suspend the background commands overlapped by it?

```
    tmux new-session "monitor1" \;\
            split-window -v "monitor2" \;\
            select-pane -U \;\
            split-window -v -h -p 60 "monitor3" \;\
            bind-key -n C-s new-window "monitor4" \;\
            bind-key -n C-q "..."
```

Answer (score 53):

Todd Freed is right, the "correct" way to do this is using `\;`.  Sort of.  But there's a snag.

You see, you join a sequence of tmux commands together by giving tmux the conjunction `;`. Thus, in a file sourced by tmux, you might say

```
new-session "monitor1" ; split-window -v "monitor2"
```

if, for some reason, you wanted that all on one line.  Now, you can give that one-line compound statement to the `tmux` command from a shell also **but** the `;` must be escaped so that the shell interprets it as another argument for `tmux`.  Thus the equivalent of the above from the shell is

```
$ tmux new-session "monitor1" \; split-window -v "monitor2"
```

Similarly, the tmux `bind-key` command takes a series of arguments which are the tmux command and arguments to run when the key is pressed.  If you wanted to bind `C-q` to the above sequence from inside a file sourced by tmux, you'd say

```
bind-key -n C-q new-session "monitor1" \; split-window -v "monitor2"
```

Here we've escaped the `;` *from tmux*, so that tmux doesn't interpret it as the end of the `bind-key` command, but as another argument to `bind-key` telling it to form a compound command as the bound value of the `C-q` key.

So what happens when we want to make tmux do that from the shell?  A whole lot of escaping.

```
$ tmux bind-key -n C-q new-session "monitor1" \\\; split-window -v "monitor2"
```

First, we have to escape the `\` *and* the `;` each from the *shell*, causing the shell to pass the two characters `\;` as an argument to `tmux`.  This then escapes the `;` from tmux, causing it to assign the entire compound statement as the binding of `C-q`.

---

Now, all that said, if you use a complex tmux setup like this repeatedly, I'd suggest that you create a tmux file to keep it in:

```
# In split-windows.tmux:
new-session "monitor1"
split-window -v "monitor2"
bind-key -n C-s new-window "monitor4"
# ...etc...
```

And then:

```
$ tmux source split-windows.tmux  # (or even make an alias for this)
```

It'll be a lot easier to maintain that way.

Comment: To make binding keys to multiple commands from the command line less horrible to look at, you can also string escape the `\;`: `$ tmux bind-key -n C-q new-session "monitor1" '\;' split-window -v "monitor2"`

Answer (score 20):

So the real answer is : you chain commands with a backslash followed by a semicolon.

```
bind-key C send-keys foo \; send-keys bar
```

You would put that in your tmux.conf, or run from the tmux ":" prompt

Comment: this was great and worked for using nested tmux session and navigating through the nested tmux windows.

Comment: This does *not* work from shell command line. I.e. `tmux bind-key C send-keys foo \; send-keys bar" has the effect of binding "foo" to "C" but prints "bar" immediately.

Comment: Yes, you would run that from within tmux. Updated to clarify.

Comment: Nice! This totally works... muchas gracias!

Comment: Note: a ; inside single quotes does not need escaping

Answer (score 2):

You are able to do this with a small workaround.  Similar to the answer suggesting a script to run (which handles your case well), it can more generally be done by using "run-shell" and calling tmux itself as the shell command.

```
bind-key z run-shell "tmux send-keys "xyz" ; tmux clear-history; clear"
```

which will send 'xyz' keys, tmux 'clear-history' command, and then call the 'clear' shell builtin.

The entire string is just a multiple shell command sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Everything shown here will not work, because this

```
bind q send-keys "command1" \; send-keys "command2"
```

will execute the command2 immediately and q will be bound only to send-keys "command1"

Here's the solution:

```
bind R source-file "$HOME/.tmux/reload.tmux"
```

In the file ~/.tmux/reload.tmux put multiple commands like:

```
source-file "$HOME/.tmux.conf" 
display-message "Configuration reloaded."
```

Comment: Oh wait, use what Peeja said (\\\;) :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can add something like this to the key bindings to your `.tmux.conf` file:

```
bind q send-keys "/home/jackhab/bin/tmux-new-session.sh" \; send-keys "Enter"
```

And in `tmux-new-session.sh` you can have:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
tmux new-session "monitor1"
tmux split-window -v "monitor2"
tmux select-pane -U
tmux split-window -v -h -p 60 "monitor3"
...
exit
```