# tmux combine multiple commands to one vi-copy command or tmux command to yank a line

Tags: linux, tmux

In tmux, i know we can chain multiple commands to a key by using \; [See Here](https://superuser.com/questions/352117/binding-a-tmux-key-to-multiple-commands)
But in vi mode, i want one single key press to go to the beginning of the current line, begin-selection, go to end-of-line, copy-selection.

In tmux.conf if i give the following 
`bind-key -t vi-copy 's' start-of-line \; begin-selection \; end-of-line \; copy-selection \;`

It gives me this `: 69: usage: bind-key [-cnr] [-t key-table] key command [arguments]` error.

Or is there any alternative way to yank the current line in single key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the mode-specific bindings (done with `-t`) currently only support one command at a time. Additionally, the command must be one of the mode-specific commands, not any general *tmux* command. In the source, the function `cmd_bind_key_check` limits the non-option arguments to exactly two when using `-t`: one key and one command; this is why you get the usage message (though the message it not very illuminating).

You can use invoke the `copy-end-of-line` command to save a couple of keystrokes though. In `vi-copy` mode: use `0 D` instead of `0 Space $ Enter`. In `emacs-copy` mode: `C-a C-k` instead of `C-a C-Space C-e C-w`.