# Shortcut to split window + ssh + cd to dir

Tags: tmux

When using `tmux`, I often do the following:

- Create a new window
- ssh to remote box
- cd to specific dir
- launch process

Now I want to tail the logfile of the process I just launched in a split. So I do the following:

- Split the window
- `ssh` to remote box  (annoying)
- `cd` to specific dir  (annoying)
- `tail -f logs/run.log`

What I wish was possible is to have a shortcut to split a window and automatically `ssh` to the same box and cd to the same dir as the parent window.

I came across the following command, which led me to believe it is possible:

```
bind-key S command-prompt -p ssh: "new-window -n %1 'ssh %1'"
```

Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: A possible half-answer might be *something like* (untested) `ssh remote-host 'cd $somedir ; $SHELL`. But I don't think you can directly get the current directory in one window and pass it to another.

Answer (score 0):

I had great troubles with having everything as a one-liner, it gets confusing with the window focus and escapes for the send-keys. If you experiment a bit you could probably get it in one line.

create a tmux file

```
# splitssh.tmux
split-window -h   
send-keys 'ssh server' 'c-m' 'cd folder' 'c-m'
'tail -f logs/run.log' 'c-m'
```

> bind-key S source splitssh.tmux

here's another link of the subject
[Binding a tmux key to multiple commands](https://superuser.com/questions/352117/binding-a-tmux-key-to-multiple-commands)

Answer (score 0):

I came across your question many months ago and was looking for the same. I finally figured out how to accomplish part of your answer, which is the hardest part (split existing SSH). First install and configure [SSHH](https://github.com/yudai/sshh) (SSH Helper) to split the current SSH session into a new pane. Then, we can make it really fast by reusing the same `ssh` connection by adding this to our SSH config:

```
ControlMaster                  auto
ControlPath                    /tmp/ssh_mux_%h_%p_%r
ControlPersist                 4h # change to whatever you like, but 4h is a good start.
```

Keep in mind that if our connection gets terminated we sometimes have to `rm --force /tmp/ssh_mux_*`. The tradeoff for superfast SSH splits is worth it!

Also, `sshh` doesn't work with Fish shell out of the box, but I figured out how to get it working, see https://github.com/yudai/sshh/issues/4.