# Run vim's :redraw! command after issuing tmux send-keys command

Tags: vim, tmux

I'm running a command to send a keystroke to another vim buffer open in a tmux terminal:

`:silent !tmux send-keys -t 1.left 'F7'`

It works, but my originating terminal goes blank and I have to issue a `:redraw!` command.

I tried `:silent !tmux send-keys -t 1.left 'F7' | :redraw!` but it looks like this is also getting sent to the other vim buffer and not the one originating the command.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping the first command with `execute` did the trick:

`execute "silent !tmux send-keys -t 1.left 'F7'" | :redraw!`

Comment: i'd guess the original treats `| :redraw!` as additional parameters to the `send-keys`, so any method of splitting them up would work.  see also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/538719/685512)