# tmux run a pipe/chain of commands with keybinding

Tags: ubuntu, shell, tmux, fish

How can I run a chain of command like in shells with tmux? I want to run multiple commands based on success of them. I want to echo out to terminal (or command bar)

E.g. I have a keybinding to reload config as follow. And I also want to output `reloaded` to tell use it happened. But this shows error for `source-file` when I trigger it.

```
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf   # works fine
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf && echo reloaded.   # doesn't work shows source-file help in command bar.
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf; echo reloaded.  # doesn't work, says not recognized 'echo'
```

And what shell will this command be called on? Default shell or current shell or foreground program running in tab/window/pane? My default shell is `fish`.

Comment: Note: the title says "pipe" but `&&` you were trying to use does not build a pipe in a shell.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yeah it's difficult to convery everything in a few words so chose those words. I did try pipe `... | echo reloaded.` but it also fails the say way as second one.

Comment: Piping to `echo` makes no sense, even in a shell where it throws no error.

Answer (score 1):

What you specify after `bind r` should be one or more [tmux commands](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#COMMANDS) (with or without arguments). `source-file ~/.tmux.conf` is a valid tmux command. `source-file ~/.tmux.conf && echo reloaded.` is not. To run more than one tmux command you need to use `;` (sometimes in a form of `\;`, see [Binding a tmux key to multiple commands](https://superuser.com/q/352117/432690) for details). But `echo` is not a tmux command.

There is however the [`run-shell`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#run-shell) tmux command that allows you to run *arbitrary* code in a shell. My tests tell me the shell is `sh` (even if my command interpreter is not `sh`). The manual confirms:

> *shell-command* arguments are `sh(1)` commands.

To run `source-file` from a shell you need to call `tmux source-file …`. This line in `.tmux.conf` should work:

```
bind-key r run-shell 'tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf && echo reloaded'
```

The output from the shell (i.e. from `echo` in this case) will appear in view mode. Personally I would like the short message to appear in the status line, so I would rather use this variant:

```
bind-key r run-shell 'tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf && tmux display-message reloaded'
```

It's quite educative to analyze what happens when you trigger this binding. You're in a tmux client that communicates with a tmux server. When the client receives a proper key sequence, <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>, it informs the server and the server acts according to the binding: it runs a shell. The shell runs another tmux client that communicates with the same tmux server and makes it execute the `source-file …` command. Then the shell runs yet another tmux client that communicates with the server and tells it to run `display-message …`.

In other words the server runs some code that spawns clients that tell the same server to do something.

Your original working binding (`bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf`) is a lot simpler, the server runs `source-file …` directly.

Since `source-file` and `display-message` are tmux commands, you can run them both upon a keystroke without spawning a shell:

```
bind-key r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message reloaded
```

One would expect `\;` here to work like `;` in a shell, but in fact it's more like `&&`. The manual [states](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#PARSING_SYNTAX):

> Each command is terminated by a newline or a semicolon (`;`). Commands separated by semicolons together form a *command sequence* - if a command in the sequence encounters an error, no subsequent commands are executed.

So this last binding seems just right in your case, it doesn't spawn any unnecessary shell. Still it's good to know you can run anything via `run-shell`, even additional tmux clients.

You can mix the two approaches:

```
bind-key r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; run-shell '#some complex logic here or whatever'
```

And there is [`if-shell`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#if-shell). Example:

```
bind-key r if-shell 'tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf' 'display-message reloaded' 'display-message "reload failed"'
```